# How can I compute the longest relaxation time?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, monte-carlo

[Cross-posted on Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641611/how-can-i-compute-the-longest-relaxation-time) and on [SciComp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/43923/27325).

In the case of Monte Carlo simulations:

- **Autocorrelation Time ($\tau_{\text{int}}$)**: A measure of how many steps are needed for the correlations in the chain to become small; it affects the variance of estimators based on the Markov chain.
- **Relaxation Time ($\tau_{\text{relax}}$)**: The time it takes for the Markov chain to approach its equilibrium distribution from an arbitrary starting point.
- **Longest Relaxation Time ($\tau_1$)**: The slowest timescale on which the system relaxes to equilibrium, which is critical for understanding the overall convergence rate of the Markov chain.

**I realize that** autocorrelation time is the sum of autocorrelation values over a given maximum lag time. So, the formula becomes:

$$
\tau_{\text{int}} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{t=1}^{\text{max-lag}} ACF(t)
$$

where $ACF()$ is the autocorrelation function:

$$
   ACF(k) = \frac{1}{(n-k)\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-k} (x_i - \mu)(x_{i+k} - \mu)
   $$

**I also realize that**, relaxation time can be found by fitting an autocorrelation value to the exponentia decay function ($A_0 \cdot e^{\frac{-t}{\tau_\text{relax}}}$).

How can I compute the **longest relaxation time**?